# Inverse Kinematics Tools

Tags: control, robotic-arm, jacobian

I am looking for inverse kinematics library (preferably compatible with ROS) that includes functions to calculate inverse-jacobian to go from end-effector velocity (twist) to joint velocities. I've only found KDL that has this capability but before implementing KDL, I would to see if there is any other options that I can use.

I also saw TRAC-IK but as I see from the source code, it only supports inverse position kinematics.

Comment: How about OpenRAVE's [IKFast](http://openrave.org/docs/0.8.2/openravepy/ikfast/)?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* kobuki, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: Have you tried... Googling your question? You have an answer yourself (KDL), and *the ROS website itself [has a tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_Fast_IK_Solution) using IKFast*.

Comment: Hey Chuck, thanks for clarification. I wanted to see what are other options are available.
@PetchPuttichai I am looking at IKFast now, thanks.